# Can I run rails application on Google AppEnging flixable environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been researching the possibility of running rails apps on google appengine using thier flixable enviroment feature.

I know that I can ruby apps on it, so I [followed this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world) and tried to tweak it a bit to get it working with rails, but I didn't know how to specify the entry point for the rails app (in the app.yaml file).

```
runtime: ruby
vm: true
entrypoint: bundle exec ruby app.rb -p $PORT
```

Is it possible? or I'm just wasting my time and should go for something else like google cloud engine or Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/runtime

the entry point should be:

```
entrypoint: rails server -p $PORT
```

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error: /bin/sh: 1: rails: not found

Answer (score 0):

The entry port on Google AppEngine Flexible should be 8080 so you entrypoint record should like this:

```
bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 8080
```

I am running few Ruby apps on GAE Flexible and it's a great environment, So I'd suggest you try it.

Comment: but you know when you run rails, there is no app.rb file. what is the entrypoint in rails app case?